# Redshift of matter-radiation equality from $T^4$

Tags: cosmology, temperature, universe, thermal-radiation, redshift

I am trying to solve the following problem.

> Argue on dimensional grounds that the energy density of blackbody
>   radiation at temperature T should scale as $T^4$. Use this to find the redshift of
>   matter-radiation equality to an order of magnitude.

The first part seems straightforward enough, assuming that that energy goes as $k_bT$ and volume goes as $(\frac{h}{k_bT})^3$;

However I am a bit puzzled as to how the $T^4$ relationship with energy density helps me to find the redshift. I would expect a much more straightforward approach: simply to take the ratio of $\Omega_m$ and $\Omega_r$, i.e.,
$$\frac{\Omega_m}{\Omega_r}-1=z$$ and use the concordance model values (which are given in this problem regardless).

However, I don't see how using $T^4$, as the problem asks, aids me. Could anyone hint me where is that used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy density of radiation scales as $a^{-4}$, since the average energy of a blackbody photon is a few $kT$, and Wien's law tells you that wavelength and $T$ are reciprocally related.

The matter energy density is $\rho c$, which scales as $a^{-3}$.

Using the present day densities you can shrink the scale factor until the energy densities of radiation and matter are the same...

Comment: May I ask, what do you mean by 'shrink'?

Comment: @Henrikas I mean as you go back in time from the present epoch, the scale factor shrinks (becomes smaller).

Comment: But does that help me? I need to use the temperature rather than $a$ (albeit they are closely related).

Comment: @Henrikas they are not closely related, they are specifically related. No more help with your homework.

Comment: Not exactly homework, as I am studying this on my own. Thank you regardless, I see what you mean, though I still find it an unintuitive approach and I don't see why I am asked to do this in this way.

Comment: @Henrikas were you given the present day radiation energy density? If not, that might be where the order of magnitude estimate comes in.

Comment: well I was given CMB temperature only, so my guess is I must work with that the way you said before.